# Eclipse won't show PHP files

Tags: php, eclipse

I'm not sure if I did anything to cause this, but when I opened up Eclipse, it would only let me view and edit HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files. If I try to open a PHP file, a blank window opens where you would normally view the file. The window has no content or title, just the "X" to close it. Anyone have any ideas what would cause this?
In case it matters, I'm using Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600

Comment: have you installed eclipse PDT (https://eclipse.org/pdt/) ?

Comment: I'll look it up, but I'm fairly certain that is what I downloaded, but it was like a year ago. This is the first time that this has happened. Before today, PHP files worked fine. Would that not be included in the IDE?

Comment: it is possible to open the file in another editor?

Comment: It worked in Notepad. I'm also currently downloading an update to the IDE that does have PDT just in case.

Comment: The update seemed to fix the issue, but none the less, if you have any ideas, I'd love to know just in case it comes up again in the future.